# Subtract array with different size in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If i have an array:

```
  A[ 1
    2
    3
    4]
```

and another array:

```
B= [1   2   3   4]
```

i wan to subtract each row in array A in each column of array B,

just like this:

```
0   1   2   3
-1  0   1   2
-2  -1  0   1
-3  -2  -1  0
```

each row in in array A was subtracted to each column in array B. each column here, represent each row in A,so how i will do that?

Comment: do you already learn about for loop? try calculate this 2 array inside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant, **SUBTRACT** each row in array `A` **FROM** each column of array `B` -

```
bsxfun(@minus,B(:).',A(:))
```

If you meant, **FROM** each row in array `A`, **SUBTRACT** each column of array `B` -

```
bsxfun(@minus,A(:),B(:).')
```

Comment: sir, the result is reverse please check again my output in my problem, thanks

Comment: @Raldenors You said `"subtract each row in array A in each column of array B"`, that's what it does! If you meant the "other way", it would be `bsxfun(@minus,B(:),A(:).')`.

Comment: @Raldenors Are you actually trying to understand what the users are answering you? Instead of asking a new question for every tiny line of code of your task or demanding corrections until the result is 1000% how you need it? It's not meant as an insult, just as an advice that it may helps you more if you actually revise the answers you get.

Comment: @Raldenors: Use a non-symmetric example to check which way is right for you. Form your question I can't tell what you really want.